# What happens in multiple APK support when a user updates it's OS?

Tags: android, google-play

I'm wondering, if I have an APK that supports for example Android 2.3.7 and below and another that supports 3.0 and above what will happen if a user with a device with 2.3.7 updates it's OS to 4.0 ?

For example, a Samsung Galaxy S II update from 2.3.X to 4.0 ?

Will the app be auto-magically replaced? Will it crash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it depends on your version numbering scheme.  If the app version that supports 3.0+ has a higher version number than the one that doesn't, the market will likely show an upgrade available.  It should update like any other app (but it may not be immediate): if the user has auto-updating on for the app, it will update itself after a while, but if not, it will appear to the user as having an update available and will wait on them to download it.  Unless the permissions are different between the versions.

Whether it crashes or not will be determined by the app itself:  what happens if you yourself install the 2.3.7 APK on a 4.0 device (which may or may not require a quick change to the manifest file)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it won't be replaced. The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/publishing/multiple-apks.html) says, that you publish multiple APKs under one Google Play (Market) entry. So if user has a specific APK which has a max-sdk parameter set in Manifest, then it won't work on newer system. But if you don't have max-sdk specified and there are no conflicts, it will.

EDIT: But as Jon O said, it should be possible for the user to update the app, because it's still the same Google Play entry.